# Next.js getServerSideProps with locales switching (slug)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I'm trying to build a simple blog using Next.js with Strapi with english and french contents. I found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iqi3ZSp1cpE) that explains how to create dynamic routes with the id of a post. I have no problem with switching locales in my Next.js app. But in this case, the URL's look at this : 
`http://localhost:3000/articles/1` 
**My question is : how to use slug to create a route like**
`http://localhost:3000/articles/my-english-article-slug`

(and that can switch between locales in Next.js)

`http://localhost:3000/fr/articles/my-french-article-slug`

---

### Here's a simple preview of my actual code :

The file is named **/articles/[id].js**

```
const Article = ({ article }) => {
  const router = useRouter()

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.single__page}>
        <h1>{article.title}</h1>
        <p>{article.content}</p>
        <Link href={router.asPath} locale={router.locale === 'en-US' ? 'fr' : 'en-US'}>
          <a>{router.locale === 'en-US' ? 'Lire en français' : 'Read in english'}</a>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { id } = context.params
  const { locale } = context

  console.log(context.params)

  let translation = undefined

  const initialRes = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/articles/${id}`)
  const initial = await initialRes.json()

  if (locale === 'fr') {
    const translationRes = await fetch(`http://localhost:1337/articles/${initial.localizations[0].id}`)
    translation = await translationRes.json()
  }

  return {
    props: {
      article: translation ? translation : initial
    }
  }
}
```

In that case, I followed the instructions in the tutorial. But I'd like to use `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`. 
 Plus, I tried to rewrite the file name with **/articles/[slug].js** and change the `getServerSideProps` calls, but it does not work.

I'm pretty new with Strapi and Next.js, and hope to find some help here!

Comment: To clarify, are you looking for a solution with `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`?

Comment: Hi Julio. Actually, a simple solution with `getServerSideProps` would be super helpful to me. After, I could decline this solution with `getStaticProps`.

Comment: What's not working with your `getServerSideProps` approach? Can you not use a slug to make the API call rather than using an ID?